# Natural lagnuage generation via RNN and csv data

Tags: python, tensorflow, nls

I'm a beginner of TensorFlow and machine learning.
I'd like to ask about how I can make some code.

I'm trying to make a natural language generation program by RNN.

you can see the picture which is data, there're x, y, vocab_size and max_len each row.
Is there a way to execute that code integrally? Each row has its own data, and the length of lists are different. If there's no way, do I have to execute each row separately?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iQxL.png)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 10, input_length=max_len-1))
model.add(SimpleRNN(32))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(dataset, epochs=200, verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually just the architecture you defined earlier should be sufficient. CMIIW

Comment: Thanks for telling me, but could you show me an example how can I execute the model with csv data? Thank you in advance

Comment: https://github.com/samyon7/Text_Generation_LSTM/blob/master/TensorFlow%20Model